# Maxima. Thread local storage exhausted

Tags: multithreading, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, maxima

I am writing mathematical modules for analysis problems. All files are compiled to .fasl.
The sizes of these files are gradually increasing and new ones are added to them. I ran into a problem today when loading a module load("foo.mac") ~0.4s loading 100+ files and another module from 200+, which declare functions and variables without precomputing.

Error: `Thread local storage exhausted fatal error encountered is SBCL pid %PRIMITIVE HALT called; the party is over. Welcome to LDB..` CPU and RAM indicators are stable at this moment

Doesn't help `maxima -X '--dynamic-space-size 2048'`, 4096 - too, by default 1024. **Why it does not work?**

SBCL + Windows = works without errors. SBCL 1.4.5.debian + Linux (server) this error is thrown. However, if I reduce the size of the files a little, then the module is loaded.

I recompiled the files, checked all .UNLISP. Changed the order of uploaded files, but an error occurs when loading the **most recent ones** in the list. Tests run without errors. There are some ways to increase the amount "local storage" through SBCL, Maxima? **In which direction to move**? Any ideas

**Update**:
Significantly reduced the load by removing duplicate code matchdeclare(..). Now no error is observed.

Answer (score 2):

From https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/mailman/message/36659152/

> maxima uses quite a few special variables which sometimes makes
> sbcl run out of thread-local storage when running the testsuite.
> They proposed to add an environment variable that allows to change
> the thread-local storage size but added a command-line option
> instead => if supported by sbcl we now generate an image with
> ab bigger default thread-local storage whose size can be
> overridden by users passing the --tls-limit option.

The `NEWS`  file in SBCL's source code also indicates that the default value is 4096

```
changes in sbcl-1.5.2 relative to sbcl-1.5.1:
  * enhancement: RISC-V support with the generational garbage collector.
  * enhancement: command-line option "--tls-limit" can be used to alter the
    maximum number of thread-local symbols from its default of 4096.
  * enhancement: better muffling of redefinition and lambda-list warnings
  * platform support:
    ** OS X: use Grand Central Dispatch semaphores, rather than Mach semaphores
    ** Windows: remove non-functional definition of make-listener-thread
  * new feature: decimal reader syntax for rationals, using the R exponent
    marker and/or *READ-DEFAULT-FLOAT-FORMAT* of RATIONAL.
  * optimization: various Unicode tables have been packed more efficiently
```